# Strongly (very) typed language

Tags: programming-languages

Could anyone please tell me if there is a language which would forbids (won't compile) if you pass an argument to a fnc which is not an exact match (but has either trivial or user defined conversion to a needed type). For example if you have:

```
void f(int value);
//and in code you passing:
bool a = false;
f(a);
```

This is strictly theoretical Q.

Comment: This is illegal in C#, Java, Haskell...

Comment: So, do you want it to *accept* or *reject* the code snippet you've shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a vague question, but all the same: Haskell, OCaml etc have this sort of behavior. If a function requires an Int - it has to be given an Int. You maybe able to write functions that coerce Ints to Bools but that doesn't change anything i.e. you still get a type error. Of course, there are languages with far more demanding type systems and complex proof obligations that Haskell and OCaml.

Scala is an interesting language where if there is a user defined coercion from one type to the other and it is non-ambiguous, the compiler will insert it for you. For example, sometimes people use it to coerce datatypes like (Int, (Int, Int)) to ((Int, Int) Int) which is handy.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think you perhaps meant converse not coerce?

Comment: @There: "type conversion", "typecasting" and "coercion" are pretty much synonymous in this context.

Comment: @delnan never came across (in books) that someone would say user defined coercion. Never. If you could cite some book (or paper) I would be more than gratefull.

Comment: @There: See the first sentence of [Wikipedia on type conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion).

Comment: @delnan +1 Thanks, every day I learn something new. To the very end I hope.